# Variable assignment in SystemVerilog generate statement

Tags: hardware, verilog, system-verilog

I have created a simple module that I replicate several times using the Verilog generate statement. However, it seems that the generate statement somehow effects variable assignment in the module. Here's the code:

```
module test();
  timeunit      10ns;
  timeprecision 1ns;

  wire[3:0] out; 
  reg[3:0] values[0:4] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

  logic clk;

  generate
    genvar i;
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++)  begin: M1
      MUT mut(
      .out,
      .in(values[i]),
      .clk
      );
    end
  endgenerate

  initial begin
    #1 clk = 0;

    $monitor("%b %b %b %b %b\n", M1[0].mut.out, M1[1].mut.out, M1[2].mut.out, M1[3].mut.out, M1[4].mut.out);

    #10 $stop;
  end

  always #1 clk++;
endmodule

module MUT(output [3:0] out, input [3:0] in, input clk);

 reg[3:0] my_reg[0:7];

 assign out = my_reg[7];

 always @(posedge clk) begin
    my_reg[7] <= in; //5
 end

endmodule
```

The expected output of this test program would be `0101 0110 0111 1000 1001`, however the output I get is `xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx`. It seems that the values in the `values` variable in the `test` module are not getting assigned to the `out` variable in the `MUT` module. However, when I replace `my_reg[7] <= in;` with say, `my_reg[7] <= 5;`, the code works as expected. The code also works when I assign directly to `out` (after declaring it as register) i.e. `out <= in;`. There's no problem if I replicate the `MUT` modules 'manually' without using any generate statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not connecting the outputs to separate wires. So they are implicitly tied together(like how it did for clock) resulting multiple drivers for a bit.

Just add

```
wire[3:0] out[0:4]; 

  generate
    genvar i;
    for (i=0; i < 5; i++)  begin: M1
      MUT mut(
      .out(out[i]),  // Connect to different wires
      .in(values[i]), 
      .clk
      );
    end
  endgenerate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize clk variable with 0.